# Play framework 2 with sass and compass config file

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt, compass-sass

I am testing stuff with scala, play framework 2.1.1 and I wanted to add sass with compass stylesheets using the compass plugin "compass-normalizer". For the sass part I am using the [jlitola plugin](https://github.com/jlitola/play-sass).

I already got play working with sass and compass but using compass plugins has proven to be a nightmare for me. I have tried adding it as a ruby requirement:

`SassPlugin.sassOptions := Seq("--compass","-r","compass-normalizer")`

This was just a try and obviously didn't work because normalizer needs compass to be already initialized, however I can make it work from the terminal if I have the contrib.rb compass config file where I call `sass #sassfile# --compass`.
In that way of thinking I tried adding the contrib.rb file in the play project with no luck. I tried to add it to the app, conf and project folders with the same luck in all of them.

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's just using the "current working directory" when running (see: https://github.com/jlitola/play-sass/blob/master/src/main/scala/SassCompiler.scala#L16).  This is using a shady implicit to convert the `Seq[String] => ProcessBuilder`.

So, you may be able to put the contrib.rb file in the default directory (should be where you're running sbt from) and have the work. If not, according to the JVM docs:

```
The default value is the current working directory of the current process, usually the     directory named by the system property user.dir.
```

So you could make a task that prints this in sbt to see what it is:

```
TaskKey[Unit]("show-user-dir") := println(sys.props("user.dir")
```

Comment: You are missing a ) on the end of that last line. Also good to know is how to run such a task from the command line. You do that by typing "sbt show-user-dir" or (if you use activator) "activator show-user-dir"